# Map Zotero fields using Dublin Core

Tags: php, plugins

I am trying to map the fields of a book in the Zotero plugin using Dublin Core but failed. My required fields are

- number of Pages
- Series
- Series number
- number of Volums
- Place
- Call Number

I've tried using this way:

```
<meta name="dc.Series" content="lorem ipsum"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/zotero/translators/blob/master/RDF.js and https://github.com/zotero/translators/blob/master/Embedded%20Metadata.js

number of pages: bibo.numPages

series: citation_series_title

series number: not currently recognized on web pages

number of volumes: bibo.numVolumes

place: not recognized

call number: not recognized

where bibo namespace refers to http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using PHP to create an HTML page about a text, with embedded Dublin Core metadata that Zotero should understand. Your problem is that Zotero doesn't understand the tags for the fields that you list (number of pages, series, number of volumes etc.).

You may want to look at [Google's instruction for listing scholarly texts](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing) for inclusion by Google Scholar. In it, defined "Dublin Core" fields are

> DC.citation.volume, DC.citation.issue, DC.citation.spage (start page), and DC.citation.epage (end page)

I found the link to these on the [Zotero documentation page about exposing metadata](http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/exposing_metadata), which also lists alternatives like COinS and unAPI.